# Open quickfix in current vertical split

Tags: vim, configuration

I usually use a layout of one vertical split and two different buffers. When i use `:copen`, the quickfix window always opens in the right split, regardless where my cursor is. Consequently, if my cursor is in the left split, and I issue the commands `:copen`, `:cclose`, the buffer is changed.

Is there any way of opening the quickfix window in the same vertical split where my cursor is?

Comment: What does `vimrc` have?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Want to have a look at your `vimrc`

Comment: https://github.com/lsund/dotfiles/tree/master/config/vimrc

Comment: I got a partial solution though `:botright copen` opens the window spanning both splits.

Answer (score 0):

As a specification, quickfix is opened in right column whenever vsplit. It is unreasonable to respond to your order...
but, perhaps it seems to work as expected;

```
command! Lcopen :copen | :wincmd p | :wincmd L | :bp | :wincmd h | :bn
```

I want you to keep in mind that it depends on Buffer's state.